# I need fo find out why doesn't re.findall work sometimes?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code to search in the url for the instagram link, and a few urls don't return back to me, even though I can find manually in the source code of the url. And the URL is not blocked because I can find the Facebook link in the same url but not instagram's.

```
import re
import requests

try:
    url = "https://www.walmart.com.br"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    page = page.text
    instagram_link = re.findall('https?://www.instagram.com/(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', page)[0]
    print("Instagram:", instagram_link)

except:
    pass
    instagram_link = "Not found"
    print("Instagram:", instagram_link)


try:
    facebook_link = re.findall('https?://www.facebook.com/(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', page)[0]
    print("Facebook:", facebook_link)

except:
    pass
    facebook_link = "Not found"      
    print("Facebook:", facebook_link)

>>> Instagram: Not found
>>> Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/walmart.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
instagram_link = re.findall('https?://www.instagram.com/(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', page)[0]
```

You forgot www in the instagram url

Comment: @Pricylla have tested your code on my IDE (pycharm) The output I've gotten from it is: 
```Instagram: https://www.instagram.com/walmartcom
Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/walmart.com```, so I would need more context on your code or what the error is

Comment: I have found the problem. Thanks a lot, it was what the guy above answered.